# how to pause onDrawFrame on opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es, ondraw

i'm quite new on using opengl, i wonder if there is any way to pause or totally stop the onDrawFrame?

and is onSurfaceCreated always called every time i return to the game page?is there any way to stop from being called?

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? You want to display a blank screen? You want the view to stop updating and show static render?

Comment: yes,i want to pause a game and then continue it later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)` to make the view only render when you call `requestRender()`. (To revert to continuous rendering use `setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY)`).

`onSurfaceCreated` is called when the surface is created, but you most likely do not want to stop this method from executing, since without it you would be left without an option to begin loading your graphics. Instead try to preserve your View/Surface if you don't want to run it all the time.